# Flex + svg behaving strange in ios Safari 14.0.3

Tags: css, flexbox, safari

So I have this simple markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <svg>...</svg>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

On **Chrome** everything is working as expected - the svg is centered in the .container class

On **Safari 14.0.3**, the svg is not being rendered by the browser, if I open the inspector and toggle the property **display: flex** off and then back on, it's showing up and works as expected.

What fallback would you use in this situation ?

Comment: Try adding `width: 100%` to the container and/or `flex:1` to the `svg`... Alternatively, put the `svg` in a `div`, making that `div` the flex item.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @que1326?

Comment: @JamesNisbet yes, in my case I had id collision ( check the below accepted answer )

Comment: My solution ended up being something to do with minimum heights/widths + flexbox + svg child element... in Safari only. Fun times!

Comment: Lost two hours to this today. Did you find a reliable fix?

Comment: @Drew check the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the **SVG** reference ids don't collide with other svgs ids. Safari it's behaving strange when you are using the same ids to reference ,  from svg definition. Chrome on the other hand doesn't care if you use the same id in different svgs.

Answer (score 4):

Giving the svg a width and height of 100% fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Confirmed it works now on iOS. Both flex and inline-flex (as well as browser prefixed versions) made the SVG fail to render on every iOS browser and took a lot of searching before finding this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the container element was a button with fixed height and width of 32px. What worked for me - adding padding to 0 for it - it had some padding from user agent stylesheet, which covered to whole inside. It shouldn't hid the svg though (only iOS mobiles), but it did :).